# Call another ASP Page dynamically with different Parameters in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I want to call another ASP Page and pass a parameter (**entry.ID**).

I have a **Master-Page Global.master** like this (I will only post a part of code):

```
<body>
<div id="global" style="height:2000px;">
    <form runat="server" id="globalForm">
        <div id="body">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="mainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                 <div id="mainContent">

                 </div>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and a **Default.aspx Page** which uses the Master-Page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
<div id="mainContent">
    <%  ICollection<Database.Blogentry> entries;
        entries = Database.BlogentryDBO.Instance.getAllBlogentries();

        foreach (Database.Blogentry entry in entries) { %>

        <div class="blogEntryBody">
            <div class="blogEntryText">
                <%= entry.Content %> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blogEntryFooter">
            <span class="blogEntryView">
                <%--CALL HERE ANOTHER PAGE WITH A BUTTON AND PASS THE PARAMETER entry.ID-->

            </span>
        </div>
    <%
        }
    %>
</div>
```

I already tried it with

```
 <label visible="false" id="LabelEntryId" name="LabelEntryId"><%= entry.ID %></label>
<asp:button ID="Button2" runat="server" class="buttonBlogEntry" text="view more ..." onclick="viewEntireBlog_onclick" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("LabelEntryId")%>' />
```

but I don't have a **CommandEventArgs** element in the onClick method but only a **EventArgs** element so I can't access my **CommandArgument**?!

And using

```
<input runat="server" type="text" id="LabelEntryId" value="<%= entry.ID %>" visible="false"/>
```

and then accessing the **input-element** in the code-behind isn't possible either, because i have more than one LabelEntryId-Input because of the loop.

Another idea was to do something like this

```
<asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" class="buttonBlogEntry" text="view more ..." onclick="<%= Response.Redirect("BlogEntrySortedByCategory.aspx?entryID=" + entry.ID); %>"/>
```

but I don't know how to do that...

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with a standard a tag?

```
<a href='/someotherpage.aspx?entryid=<%= entry.Id %>'>View more</a>
```

Comment: Sometimes the old usual things are better than the new ones...It works, thank you really much!